# where can we store excel sheet globally so that we can read the data by excel reader class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng, excel-reader

I know about how we can read the excel sheet from the local system but i want to know about if there is an excel sheet which can handle by the organization which can be modified by others too where we can store that and how can we read the excel sheet in selenium java

I have tried to read the excel sheet through excel reader from local system but I want to know from where can we store our excel sheet and read that excel sheet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.